# Blender 2.80 full release is not opening on my IMac

Tags: osx

Blender 2.80 full release is not opening on my mac am running an iMac osx late 2012 version 10.9.5 Macintosh HD with a 2.9 GHz Intel Core i5 Processor and 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 of Memory and an NVIDIA Geforce GTX Graphics card I tried restarting my mac and I also tried re-downloading blender 2.80 here is what it says when I try to open blender in the terminal [image]

Comment: it won't open, I've got a version of 2.8 that opens on Mac but not the last release, so either download a previous version of 2.8 or download 2.79

Comment: or maybe install a more recent system

Comment: Blender 2.8 has a minimum requirement of macOS 10.12. See: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/